# Export chinese words from VC++ text

Tags: visual-c++, translation

I have multiple VC++ files that look something like this.

[image]

I am wondering if it's possible to export all of the Chinese content into one file? Preferably line by line.

Comment: Do you mean the Chinese strings that are used in the code ?  Or also the programme's comments as suggested by your screenshot ? An what encoding is used (check in File -> advanced saving options)  ?

Comment: At line 1597 after // there are Chinese symbols, I want to export just this into a notepad. Chinese symbols are not always after // or in "ShortMsg" command.